# Ubuntu 13.04 and java GUI

Tags: 13.04, java, gui

I'm working on Rescue Agent Simulation, we have a main server that run our code and its programmed in Java.
Our server has lag under Ubuntu 13.04, but it run smoothly in Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04.
So my question is, What is the different in these versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: Which versions of Java do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

The default java is java-icedtea.
It caused me a lot of problems/freezing for me to.

I installed [Sun Java](http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp) and the performance is drastically improved.
You should try with that, just follow the instruction and let me know if you have any problems

Comment: I have this problem with OpenJDK 7 and Oracle Java 7 too :(

Comment: What browser do you use?
Did you link oracle java with plugins directory?

Comment: I am using  Oracle Java 7  , and its working just fine with any issue.

Comment: maybe its also a general performance problem cause by the OS due to the fact that the new OS Version per default has more processes/tasks running.